# MySQL: Finding existences between values in database and array

Tags: mysql, arrays, comparison, updates

I'd like to know how can I make a unique query to find which values exist and which values do not. I explain.

### What I have

I've got a database table with a structure as follows:

```
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
| id | action | button_id |   type    |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |      1 |         1 | button    |
|  2 |      2 |         4 | button    |
|  3 |      1 |         2 | attribute |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

As you can see, an `action` can have multiple `button_id` values. For your knowledge, a `button_id` can be assigned to multiple `action`, too, but a `button_id` can only have a `type` for an action.

So, `button_id` 1 can be also present in `action` 4 with the `type` "attribute" set to it, but it cannot be duplicated to the same action with another `type`.

### The problem

The problem comes when I want to **update the buttons in an action**. I receive an `action` object with an array of the buttons it have (in PHP) with the structure below (I write it in JSON structure):

```
"buttons":
    [
       {
          "id":"1",
          "type":"button"
       },
       {
          "id":"3",
          "type":"attribute"
       }
    ]
```

As you can see, the button with ID 1 remains the same, but I've got a new button to deal with (the button with ID 3) and the button with ID 2 is not present anymore.

### What I'd want

I'd want to be able to make a **unique MySQL query** that returns me which values from those I receive exists and which do not, and which may be present in the database but not in that array.

**To sum up:** I want to know the differences between the buttons in the array received and those present in the database.

So, **as an example** with the received data described before and the database as we have it right now, **I expect to receive** something like this:

```
+--------+-----------+--------+------------+
| action | button_id | exists | is_present |
+--------+-----------+--------+------------+
|      1 |         1 |      1 |          1 |
|      1 |         2 |      1 |          0 |
|      1 |         3 |      0 |          1 |
+--------+-----------+--------+------------+
```

With this information, **I'd be able to know** that button with ID 2 does not exist anymore (because it's not present in the new array) and button with ID 3 is a new button because it does not exists previously but it's present in the new array.

### What I've tried

There are some tests I've tried, but none of them gives me what I need, and not only tested with MySQL pure queries.

For example, I've tried to check the existence for each button I receive but that would leave me without being able to find if a button is deleted (so it's not present in the received array).

Checking that but taking as reference the buttons in the database has the same effect, as I will be able to check which have been updated or deleted, but it would skip those that are new and not present in the database.

I've tried to write some queries making `COUNT` queries and `GROUP BY` button_id, and so, but no luck neither.

*(I won't write the queries because none of them have given me the expected results, so they won't be of any help for you).*

**Any combination of those explained before I think will be much slower than doing it purely by database queries, and that's why I'm asking for it.**

### The question

Is there a query that would return to me something like the response explained before in "What I'd want" section, so it would **make only a call to the MySQL server**?

**Thank you all for your time, your responses and your patience for any lack of information you may find by my part.**

*Of course, any doubts, questions you have or information you may need, comment it and I'll try to explain it better or to add it.*

**Kind regards.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that in a single query would be very cubersome.  Here is a solution that is not exactly what you are looking for but should do the job.

Let's say your table looks like this :

```
CREATE TABLE htmlComponent
(
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  action int,
  button_id int not null,
  type varchar(20),
  dtInserted datetime,
  dtUpdated datetime
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX buttonType ON htmlComponent(button_id, type);
```

Now we need to update the table according to the buttons / atributes you have for a specific action.

```
-- Reset dtInserted and dtUpdated for action 1
UPDATE htmlComponent SET dtInserted = null, dtUpdated = null WHERE action=1;

-- INSERT or UPDATE according to the data inside the json structure
INSERT INTO htmlComponent (action, button_id, type, dtInserted)
VALUES
  (1, 1, 'button', NOW()),
  (1, 3, 'attribute', NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  button_id = VALUES(button_id),
  type = VALUES(type),
  dtInserted = null,
  dtUpdated = NOW();

 -- Getting the result
SELECT * FROM htmlComponent where action=1;
```

Your should end up with this result which will make it easy to figure out what doesn't exists anymore, what is new and what was updated.

```
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| ID | ACTION | BUTTON_ID | TYPE      | DTINSERTED                 | DTUPDATED                  |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| 1  | 1      | 1         | button    | (null)                     | February, 09 2015 16:21:49 |
| 3  | 1      | 2         | attribute | (null)                     | (null)                     |
| 4  | 1      | 3         | attribute | February, 09 2015 16:21:49 | (null)                     |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b369/3).  Please note I had to put the `UPDATE` and the `INSERT` in the left panel because DML are not allowed in the query panel.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I'll give it a try and I'll see what I can do!

Comment: Well! It turns out I could not change the database structure to suit this operations, so I made it the "less good" way (that is, multiple queries and checks with PHP). However, if I could have been able to do so, your answer would have been one of the possible ways to do it, so I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you again for your help!